# Different evaluation when compiling with -O3

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, while-loop, evaluation

The following Code has different behavior, when it is compiled with `g++ -O3 ..` and without `-O3`.

I know that `updateError` is not returning anything, which can lead to undefined behavior. What i don't understand is, that `error` is set to zero inside the loop if compiled with -O3, and `if(error > eps)` is evaluated as false, while it is still evaluated as true in the `while()` statement. .

I have also tried to change it to a do{}while() loop, in that case it worked also with -O3...

```
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;


double updateError(){
    printf("updating Error\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    double eps = 1.e-10;
    double error = 2*eps;
    int iter = 0;

    while(error > eps){
        error = updateError();
        iter++;
        printf("Error on iteration %i: %.20e\n", iter, error);
        if(error > eps) printf("error bigger\n\n");
        else printf("error smaller\n\n");
        if(iter == 5){
            printf("not converged in 5 iterations!!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Console output with -O3:

```
updating Error
Error on iteration 1: 0.00000000000000000000e+00
error smaller

updating Error
Error on iteration 2: 0.00000000000000000000e+00
error smaller

updating Error
Error on iteration 3: 0.00000000000000000000e+00
error smaller

updating Error
Error on iteration 4: 0.00000000000000000000e+00
error smaller

updating Error
Error on iteration 5: 0.00000000000000000000e+00
error smaller

not converged in 5 iterations!!
```

Console output without -O3:

```
updating Error
Error on iteration 1: 6.92743341769227318242e-310
error smaller
```

Comment: It's not "it can lead to undefined behaviour". *It is* Undefined behaviour. Compiler is allowed to do absolutely anything with that code, **in particular** when optimizing code.

Comment: *I know that updateError is not returning anything, which can lead to undefined behavior* Not can but **will**.  Analyzing your code while it has UB in it is pointless.  Since the path of execution encounters UB your entire program becomes UB and anything can happen at any time.

Comment: You might want to check the generated assembly and compare the optimized build with the unoptimized. A good way to do that is through the [compiler explorer site](https://godbolt.org/z/YCKAIG). As can be seen there can be quite a difference!

Comment: On my system, the output is `runtime error: execution reached the end of a value-returning function without returning a value`

Comment: You explicitly write an undefined behaviour and you ask a question about why the program doesn't behave as you would expect. UB means that you cannot expect anything (or in other word, anything can happen). This question sounds like _"I had a toy, I destroyed it with a hammer. Can you explain why is it broken now ?"_ :)

Comment: There was cppcon about optimization flags, where it was explained why `-O3` can have weird results for floating point operations (and in general it is not recommended for crucial calculations). I will try to find link to this talk ([maybe this is that](https://youtu.be/w5Z4JlMJ1VQ)).

Answer (score 11):

> I know that updateError is not returning anything, which can lead to undefined behavior.

There is no "can". Your code has undefined behaviour. Period.

On debug builds the compiler does some stuff extra to enhance the usage of a debugger. This can be things like initializing variables when they actually dont have to be. Such overhead is not done in optimized builds. Anyhow, if you want to understand why you get the results you get you should take a look at the assembly. Just be aware that UB is UB, so you have no guarantee that on the next day you get the same results with the same compiler.

> What i don't understand is, that error is set to zero inside the loop if compiled with -O3, and if(error > eps) is evaluated as false, while it is still evaluated as true in the while() statement. .

Note that the code you write is not translated line by line to instructions of your CPU. Compilers are rather clever and apply all kinds of transformations under the as-if rule. As long as the observable behaviour is the same the compiler is allowed to turn your code into something that is  quite different from a naive line-by-line translation. If however your code has UB, then it is not valid c++ code and getting differnt output for one and the same variable is not a big surprise.

Comment: As a side note, here's it's **obvious** UB. Sometimes, it's less obvious. In that case, I suggest to run the binary under Valgrind, it'll report `Conditional move depends on uninitialized value` errors that **must** be fixed.

Comment: Compiler are deterministic. So the next day, you'll get the same result with the same compiler. What you probably meant is that you might not get the same program output when run another time, since the program is currently picking whatever register state for return of `updateError` and because of random placement of the program in memory when loaded, it can be different.

Comment: @xryl669 well it was a bit sloppy. Maybe you get the same result, but I highly doubt that a compiler will make any guarantees about it

Comment: I see, so is there any reason it is allowed to not return a variable in a non void function?

Comment: @atsteich the point is: it is not allowed. Problem is just that in general the compiler cannot decide whether this is the case easily. In your simple example you should get a warning, but note that there are many things that are not allowed but the compiler is not required to issue an error